# EC2 Instance Vanished

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04

We have a peculiar situation today where we see that one of our EC2 instance has disappeared from the console and we weren't sure what caused this. Cloudtrail doesn't have any terminated event against this instance-id.

The last noted cloudtrail event for the instance-id that went down goes something like this

```
{
    "eventVersion": "1.08",
    "userIdentity": {
        "type": "AWSService",
        "invokedBy": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
    },
    "eventTime": "2022-03-23T05:46:40Z",
    "eventSource": "sts.amazonaws.com",
    "eventName": "AssumeRole",
    "awsRegion": "ap-south-1",
    "sourceIPAddress": "ec2.amazonaws.com",
    "userAgent": "ec2.amazonaws.com",
    "requestParameters": {
        "roleArn": "arn:aws:iam::2************:role/ec2-instance-***********",
        "roleSessionName": "i-06135ad01bb90****"
    },
    "responseElements": {
        "credentials": {
            "accessKeyId": "<redacted>",
            "sessionToken": "<redacted>",
            "expiration": "Mar 23, 2022, 12:01:34 PM"
        }
    },
    "requestID": "d9882911-39e7-449b-9701-***********"",
    "eventID": "0fa1b79b-08aa-48e6-8232-***********"",
    "readOnly": true,
    "resources": [
        {
            "accountId": "2************",
            "type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
            "ARN": "arn:aws:iam::2************:role/ec2-instance-***********"
        }
    ],
    "eventType": "AwsApiCall",
    "managementEvent": true,
    "recipientAccountId": "2************",
    "sharedEventID": "4b842373-e89d-438b-be3b-*********",
    "eventCategory": "Management"
}
```

The only thing that I can think of is either a hardware failure from AWS side or some crude command ran within the OS by some user that took the instance down. Unfortunately we dont have AWS developer support as that's quite costly.

Has anyone faced anything similar? Any leads on how i can go ahead to find the root cause?

Comment: Are you looking in the correct region?

Comment: Yes, I'm in the right region. All of our infra is in ap-south-1 and only 1 instance is missing, I see all others asusual.

Comment: You would typically see some kind of notification from AWS if there were a hardware failure. Also, you should be able to see the instance in the AWS console for a period of time, listed as terminated, and you can view the instance's system console. FYI developer support is the greater of $29 or 3% of monthly AWS charges (in the US anyway).

Comment: When a similar issue happened to me, I reached out to support. They looked at the logs and said underlying hardware provisioning the instance failed. When that happens, you do not see anything in cloudtrail.

Comment: A good use-case for enabling [Termination Protection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/terminating-instances.html#Using_ChangingDisableAPITermination).

Comment: *Day2*: Still no signs of the instance whatsoever, we firmly believe there is no human involvement. Will keep it posted when there is any progress.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is interested or may face this in future, we had to opt for AWS developer support to get an answer, here is what they had to say

---

> From the case notes, I understood that the instance
> 'i-06135ad01bb******' was missing from yesterday. However, you tried
> to check cloudtrail and could not find any traces of termination.
> Please correct me if I misunderstood your query.
>
> Upon reviewing the case description, I started checking the instance
> using our internal tools and observed that the instance got terminated
> on '2022-03-23 06:33 UTC' with the reason
> 'INSTANCE-INITIATED-SHUTDOWN'.
>
> This means that the shutdown got initiated from OS. Please allow me to
> inform you that AWS engineers do not have access or visibility to the
> customer's instance/OS level due to data privacy[1] and shared
> responsibility model[2]. Hence, I will not be in a position to check
> how shutdown call got initiated.
>
> To further investigate this, I checked using our internal tools and
> could see that you have selected the 'termination' option: on shut
> down which means that when an instance gets shutdown it will be
> automatically terminated. So, I would request you to change the option
> 'termination' : on shut down to 'STOP' : on shut down. With this, if
> the OS initiates a shutdown by any chance, the instance will be
> stopped instead of getting terminated.
> As per my analysis, I can confirm that the AWS infrastructure was healthy and there weren't any issues from our end. However, for the future, I would request you to consider the following best practices which you already might be aware of, however I am mentioning them here for the sake of completeness:
>
> 1. Enable termination protection
> 2. Regularly back up your data
> 3. Preserving root volume after termination:

---

Answer (score 0):

Thank You fannymug. I think this was the case also for me.

Just to add up:
in cloudtrail search for the instance ID and select the RunInstances eventName
here it is possible to check the event details.
Double check the value for deleteOnTermination value. If it is set to true,  termination protection is not enabled.

To avoid this, during EC2 creation process, look in advanced details > Termination Protection > Enable.
Shutdown behavior option can also help and can be set to Stop.

I hope it helps